# Google App Engine - Can't Update Budget

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-cloud-platform

I have billing enabled on my project, and have even issued a $10 payment just to test out the process (it works). But I am unable to change my daily budget on the google app engine dashboard.

1. I go to "Billing Status" section.
2. I am entering the new daily budget and I hit the "submit" button.
3. I am getting the not very informative error: "There was an error processing the request".

So I'm stuck without being able to update my budget, and my quota has exceeded for instance hours. My users are receiving errors and I am losing money, without any option of reaching out to Official Google Support (tried to email support - it can take up to a couple of days for them to get back to you, and the phone number requires a PIN that only premium customers get. becoming a premium customer also takes a couple of days...).

Any suggestions?

I have already tried:

1. making sure I have only one Google account signed in while changing the budget
2. replacing payment method
3. adding another user as a billing admin and changing the budget with that user

Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: After reaching out to a developer advocate from Google, I found out that they are aware of this issue. They claim to have solved it last night, and for me the bug is now solved.