# Google App Engine: Unable to find 'increasing daily budget'

Tags: google-app-engine, payment

I can't find it.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing talks about it but doesn't say where.

This [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786487/google-app-engine-cant-update-budget) says it's in the billing section, but the billing section lists my billing accounts and inside an account I can't find it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the new console, you can change your billing from your App Engine settings:
https://console.developers.google.com/project/**your-app-id**/appengine/settings

Make sure you've linked your project to a billing account. To do this, head over to your project-level settings:
https://console.developers.google.com/project/**your-app-id**/settings

If that still doesn't work, try the old console:
https://appengine.google.com/billing/billing_status?&app_id=**s~your-app-id**.

You must prepend the "s~" to your App ID in the old console URL if your app uses High Replication Datastore (very likely).

Comment: I can't. Can see/edit "Google login cookie expiration", "Referrers" and "Activation date" only. Nothing about billing or daily budget.

Comment: Make sure you've linked your project to a billing account. To do this, head over to your project-level settings: https://console.developers.google.com/project/your-app-id/settings

If that still doesn't work, try the old console: https://appengine.google.com/billing/billing_status?&app_id=s~your-app-id.

You must prepend the "s~" to your App ID in the old console URL if your app uses High Replication Datastore (very likely).

Comment: I found it in the old console. Thank you! Still wondering where it should be in the new console / why it's not there.

Comment: No prob :). It seems they're still figuring things out with the new console. I've updated the answer if you don't mind marking it as closed.